# IIS 8.5 Two HTTPS Sites same IP same port. 2nd site throws "server IP address could not be found"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have an IIS on server 2012 R2, and two https sites:

[image]
[image]

Both of them are properly directed to my server (I checked it using https://dnschecker.org/#A), both of them has it's own certificate.

[image]

My problem is, 2nd site throw this error:

```
server IP address could not be found
```

What else I must to setup on my server?

Is something wrong with my bindings ?

Comment: Shouldn't you have the bindings on the external IP address?

Comment: @JonasÄppelgran Sorry but don't understand what exactly it means, When I edited the bindings, it only shows my local ip, external 443 traffic is routed to it.